# How to call function from another JS File A inside JS File B with ZURB Foundation/webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, zurb-foundation

Im using ZURB Foundation 6.4 (ZURB Template) which is webpack4 based and I have a function `helloAsync()` inside JS File A which is being called by `getProductnameElements()` inside JS File B.

Both JS scripts are included via `<script src=...></script>` on the layout/landing page. However, when I trigger `SayIt()`, which then calls hello(), I get the good old reference error saying that `hello()` is undefined.

Both functions work fine as long as they are not trying to call each other (across fileborders^^).

EDIT:
Codesamples

```
//script B
$("#AJAXproductnames").on("click",function(){
   getProductnameElements()
})


function getProductnameElements(){
  let productNameElements = document.getElementsByClassName('customProductCardName')
  console.log("result is ", productNameElements)
  helloAsync()
}

//script A

async function helloAsync(){
console.log("hello Async")
let response =  await getThatJSON()
console.log("response was propagated upwards and is ", response)
}


//html
//page
<button class="button" id="AJAXproductnames">FillMyProducts!</button>

<div class ="grid-container">
  <div class ="grid-x grid-padding-x">

    {{#repeat 6}}
    <div class="cell large-4">
      {{>ecommerce-product-card}}
    </div>
    {{/repeat}}

  </div>
</div>

//layout/landing page where html from page is injected
{{!-- This is the base layout for your project, and will be used on every page unless specified. --}}

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{page}}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{root}}assets/css/app.css">
  </head>
<body>

{{> multilevel-offcanvas-menu}}

{{!-- Pages you create in the src/pages/ folder are inserted here when the flattened page is created. --}}
{{> body}}

{{> contact-panel}}

<script src="{{root}}assets/js/app.js"></script>

{{#if chartPlugin}}
<script src="{{root}}assets/js/appCharts.js"></script>
{{/if}}

{{#if eCommerce}}
<script src="{{root}}assets/js/appECommerce.js"></script>
{{/if}}






</body>
</html>
```

The included scripts REQUIRE the files containing the ACTUAL js, here they are:

```
//app.js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'what-input';
import Chart from 'chart.js';


// Foundation JS relies on a global varaible. In ES6, all imports are hoisted
// to the top of the file so if we used`import` to import Foundation,
// it would execute earlier than we have assigned the global variable.
// This is why we have to use CommonJS require() here since it doesn't
// have the hoisting behavior.
window.$ = $;
window.jQuery = $;
require('foundation-sites');
require('./lib/custom');
//require('./lib/chartLogic');


//require('Chart')

// If you want to pick and choose which modules to include, comment out the above and uncomment
// the line below
//import './lib/foundation-explicit-pieces';

$(document).foundation();



//appECommerce.js
require('./lib/eCommerceLogic')
```

Comment: It might be helpful to post some of your code here.

Comment: @switchboard.op 
did it!